# How can i get audience size of exactly target ID?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

i have a graph facebook url like this

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/act_ad_account_id/targetingsuggestions?targeting_list=[{'type':'interests','id':123456}]&access_token=my_access_token
```

but this url doesn't response exactly target ID information which i want to, it's always return list of data which have multi target ID ( even not have the ID what i want to search )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Ad Account Targetingsuggestions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/targetingsuggestions/) endpoint Retrieve suggestions for given targeting specs.

If you already have the ID, you can simply use the id in the endpoint, as example:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/<interest_id>
```

As example:

```
curl -i -X GET \
 "https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/6003584163107?access_token=<token>"


{
  "id": "6003584163107",
  "name": "Advertising",
  "audience_size": 547950040,
  "path": [
    "Interests",
    "Business and industry",
    "Advertising"
  ],
  "description": "",
  "topic": "Business and industry"
}
```

Comment: thank you so much. You save my day. Could i have one more question? Can i break down the audience size by country.. Ex: i just want to get audience size of target ID in US ...

Comment: You're welcome. You can use the [Ad Account Reachestimate](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/reachestimate/) API. Feel free to open a new question with your code in case of problems